# Изменить формат даты

Tags: дата, php, datetime

Получаю дату строкой в таком формате: `14 июня 2014`

Как эту строку привести к виду: `d.m.Y`?

Answer (score 2):

Если формат даты фиксирован, то простой велосипед:

```
$months = array( 'января' => '01', /* ... */ 'июня' => '06' /* ... */ );
$date = "14 июня 2014";
$parts = explode( ' ', $date );
$format = "$parts[0].".$months[$parts[1]].".$parts[2]";
```

Если попадается всякое, то [творчески](http://habrahabr.ru/post/204628/) :)